# Is it possible to call a variable from another function in another function?

Tags: python, gensim

I wish to use a variable like a model that has trained certain sentence for gensim. 
Example, I use gensim word2vec to train a sentence to find its vectors in another function and save it to a variable called "model".

Then I create another function to get the the vectors of each word and return it.

My code is as follow:

```
def gen(sentence):
    model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec([sentence],min_count=1, workers=1, size=3)
    ....
    ....
    return ...

def name(sentence):
    for word in sentence:
        print(model.wv[word])
    return
```

Is there a way to pass the variable from function def "gen" named "model" to function def "name"? I tried to use self but its not working. I wanted to just call the variable because I dont want to build another extra function just to link it.

Comment: are you saying you want to be able to pass the variable into a different function while still inside a  function?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to pass the variable in function def gen() to def name() ..... reason because is the model has been trained with certain values and it has contain some values within this variable so if I pass it to another function. I will be able to use back the values stored in the variable and perform printing on some values based on the trained ones.

Answer (score 0):

The case when functions have to share variables is a classical motivation of the object-oriented programming. You can turn those function to be members of a class with an attribute `self.model`, initialized in `__init__(self)` as `self.model = None`:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.model = None

    def gen(self, sentence):
        self.model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec([sentence],min_count=1, workers=1, size=3)
        ...

    def name(self, sentence):
        ...

# below is a test
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentence = 'sadfdsafesafsdf'
    my_obj = MyClass()
    something_returned = my_obj.gen(sentence)
    something_else_returned = my_obj.name(sentence)
```

Then you modify that variable by calling the function `gen()` and use it in the function `name()`.

Comment: I tried this method before but it didnt work since I wanted to use the model within def name like I shown in the example. I wanted to print it in my def name(): for word in sentence:
        print(model.wv[word]) and return it

Comment: I don't see the problem. Can't you use print(self.model.wv[word])?

Comment: I tried and I received this. TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. Since we declare it to be None in the init then should it be none even when we pass it to another function. And the def gen () function variable named "model" has already stored with certain values. If I were to call a none type into another function example def name() and perform another model = gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec(...) again then it will get a new values that is different from the def gen()

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just call the function, in your other function, I made a basic example not sure if I'm misunderstanding you

```
def multiply(c):
    t = add(1, 4)
    c *= t
    return c

def add(a, b):
    t = a + b
    return t

x = multiply(2)
print(x)
```

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python/stack_overflow$ python3.7 example.py 
> 10
> ```

Comment: This works only if I dont want to make it like this: y = add(1,1) print(y). Because inside def add there is no multiply c. so if I call function add then it wont contain multiply of c. (since we are referring to multiply and adding so it became weird to explain) Generally, I have to call the function def add() and not function def multiply but function def add should contain the value for c. (Again, this becomes weird since we are referring to mul + Add, when we refer to this, usually we can just call multiply function but my problem is not like multiply and adding) thank you